# Logistic regression - Calculating cost function returns wrong results

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, logistic-regression, gradient-descent

I just started taking Andrew Ng's course on [Machine Learning](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/) on Coursera.
The topic of the third week is logistic regression, so I am trying to implement the following cost function.

[image: Cost function]

The hypothesis is defined as: 
[image: Hypothesis]

where g is the sigmoid function: 
[image: Sigmoid]

This is how my function looks at the moment:

```
function [J, grad] = costFunction(theta, X, y)

m = length(y); % number of training examples
S = 0;
J = 0;

for i=1:m
    Yi = y(i);
    Xi = X(i,:);
    H = sigmoid(transpose(theta).*Xi);
    S = S + ((-Yi)*log(H)-((1-Yi)*log(1-H)));
end

J = S/m;

end
```

Given the following values

```
X = [magic(3) ; magic(3)];
y = [1 0 1 0 1 0]';
[j g] = costFunction([0 1 0]', X, y)
```

j returns   0.6931    2.6067    0.6931 even though the result should be j = 2.6067. I am assuming that there is a problem with Xi, but I just can't see the error.

I would be very thankful if someone could point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are supposed to apply the sigmoid function to the dot product of your parameter vector (theta) and input vector (`Xi`, which in this case is a row vector). So, you should change

```
H = sigmoid(transpose(theta).*Xi);
```

to

```
H = sigmoid(theta' * Xi'); % or sigmoid(Xi * theta)
```

Of course, you need to make sure that the bias input 1 is added to your inputs (a row of 1s to `X`).

Next, think about how you can vectorize this entire operation so that it can be written without any loops. That way it would be considerably faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
function [J, grad] = costFunction(theta, X, y)
    m = length(y);
    J = 0;
    grad = zeros(size(theta));
    J=(1/m)*((-y'*(log(sigmoid(X*theta))))-((1-y)'*(log(1-(sigmoid(X*theta))))));
    grad=(1/m)*(X'*((sigmoid(X*theta))-y));
end
```

The above code snippets works perfectly fine for Logistic Regrssion Cost and Gradient functions given the sigmoid function is working fine.