# Logistic Regression Cost Function Fluctuates With any Step Size

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, gradient-descent, backpropagation

I finished [Andrew Ng's ML course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning), except I just couldn't understand backpropagation. So, I'm following the tutorial on [Neural Networks and Deep Learning](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap2.html#the_four_fundamental_equations_behind_backpropagation) to create my own neural network with Numpy. But **my logistic regression training cost function fluctuates a lot no matter what step size** (see *alpha* variable in equations at the end) **I use in gradient descent**.

I was graphing the training cost (blue, fluctuating problem) and the test cost to create a learning curve. I wanted to figure out if the model had high bias or high variance. **It's weird that my test cost doesn't fluctuate, though I use the same logistic regression cost function for both test and training costs.** (I don't have regularisation in either case).
[image: Test cost vs training cost learning curve]

---

**You can run my code yourself [on Kaggle here](https://www.kaggle.com/madhavmalhotra/first-neural-network-notebook86891cd2ac)**

---

**This is what I've tried to debug my code**

- I tried alpha in range 0.1 to 0.000000000001 decreasing by a factor of 10 each time
- I tried to increase the batch size (from 20 to 70 in increments of 10) in case the spikes in the training cost were due to inaccurate parameter updates from low batch size.
- I double-checked my implementation of backpropagation against the [MUCH CLEANER implementation](https://github.com/mnielsen/neural-networks-and-deep-learning/blob/master/src/network.py) in Neural Networks and Deep Learning :D The only difference I can see is that he doesn't sum his bias partial derivatives over all examples? See his line [104 and 116](https://github.com/mnielsen/neural-networks-and-deep-learning/blob/master/src/network.py#L104) and my [#Gradients to Return](https://www.kaggle.com/madhavmalhotra/first-neural-network-notebook86891cd2ac?scriptVersionId=68345112&cellId=7) section.
- I searched up other people's issues with implementing neural networks while following Andrew Ng's ML course. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57122161/logistic-regression-the-cost-function-is-not-decreasing) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31325834/logistic-regression-calculating-cost-function-returns-wrong-results/31326180) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44753116/coursera-ml-implementing-regularized-logistic-regression-cost-function-in-pyth) all had coding issues in their implementation. **It could entirely be I also have a coding issue in my implementation :-(** This is my second time trying to implement backpropagation (I gave up last time). But I did check that I didn't have the same issues as those questions.

---

**These are the theoretical equations I'm using:**
[image: Logistic Regression Cost Function]
*C* is for the Cost, *m* is the number of training examples, *K* is the number of output classes, *y* is a *m* by *K* matrix with true/false labels for all classes for each example, *h* is a *m* by *K* matrix with predictions for all classes for each example, and *theta* is a vector with all parameters (weights and biases).

[image]

*Alpha* is the 'step size' that I'm making smaller to minimise fluctuations in cost. The nabla notation is partial derivative of the cost with respect to all elements of theta. I compute this with the equations shown in [Neural Networks and Deep Learning](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap2.html#the_four_fundamental_equations_behind_backpropagation).

Comment: I was checking your code and stopped at the images size location. It won't work in any condition. First, your NN is too shallow to handle such a resolution. A (100,100) image can't be handled by it. You should give it some structured data.

Comment: @AbhishekPrajapat Thank you for your comment :-) I understand that the neural network is too shallow. I was just intending to make a 'rough' model as Andrew Ng put it, just to see if my implementation of backpropagation was correct. Then, I was planning on increasing the network size. 

What do you mean by giving it some structured data? Isn't my data structured - image pixels as x features and image labels as y?

Comment: @AbhishekPrajapat Sorry, I looked up what structured data is. I should've done that before commenting. Why would structured data help? Is it because I can use a simpler neural network to test my implementation of backpropagation and still have it be accurate?

Comment: Yes but partially. Well, the thing is that structure data contains obvious patterns in terms of values. Say age = 43 then the model knows it's a child. But given an image(100, 100) there is no particular value that tells that the age of the person in the image is say 43, you can only do that if you see a pattern and large models create that hidden pattern obvious for the classifier.

Comment: @AbhishekPrajapat I tried it on a churn modelling dataset with 10 inputs and 1 output. ([Kaggle Notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/madhavmalhotra/churn-neural-network-notebook281fcc46c6) and [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/shubh0799/churn-modelling)). Still incomprehensible [fluctuations in cost](https://ibb.co/HBXHVdc).

Comment: your implementation of `cost function` is wrong. You should take another look at it and compare it with "Andrew Ng." lectures. Also, your implementation is very messy with all those `.reshape()` functions. I just googled a notebook and you should take a look at < a href="https://github.com/amanchadha/coursera-deep-learning-specialization/blob/master/C1%20-%20Neural%20Networks%20and%20Deep%20Learning/Week%203/Planar%20data%20classification%20with%20one%20hidden%20layer/Planar_data_classification_with_onehidden_layer_v6c.ipynb"> this </a>.

Comment: @AbhishekPrajapat I appreciate you taking the time to look! I understand the implementation is messy :-( I'm getting a lot of broadcasting errors, which is why I used `.reshape()`. 

I looked at that notebook and I fixed some errors in my regularisation (though that was off to begin with) and my output error term (I didn't need to multiply by the derivative of the sigmoid function). I still have the same [fluctuating learning curve](https://ibb.co/bR3cY3Q), though my [gradient descent cost over time](https://ibb.co/sCxpPg7) looks normal :) Here's the [updated code](https://cutt.ly/2Qr0yqy)